# Sas changing of date format

Tags: date, sas

I have three columns with date formatted differently in SAS:

1. `12 june 2017 00:15` - full date
2. `2016` - only year
3. `12` - only month

I Need to change the format of date and subtract after the dates to get results in the number of months.

for instance, `"12 June 2017 00:15" - December 2016 = 7`

how to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about a raw datafile or a SAS dataset?  Are any of these variables character strings instead of numbers?  Is the first one a numeric variable with a valid SAS datetime value? If so there isn't really a format that will display it in exactly the way you are showing.  Are you asking how to convert (1) and (2 and 3 together) into date values?

Comment: Its a Sas Dataset. First column is date format, second and third are numeric.

Comment: First one does not look like a date. Looks like a date time, since it has a time component.

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably already found, there isn't a ready-made [SAS date informat](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm) that will correctly handle your full date field, so you'll need to write a bit of custom logic to convert it before doing your calculation. `date9.` is the closest matching format I could find:

```
data example;
fulldate = '12 june 2017 00:15';
year = 2016;
month = 12;
/* Convert string to date9 format and input */
fulldate_num = input(
  cats(
    scan(fulldate,1),
    substr(scan(fulldate,2,' '),1,3),
    scan(fulldate,3)
  ), date9.
);
/* Calculate difference in months */
monthdiff = intck('month', mdy(month,1,year), fulldate_num);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the "full date" field to a SAS date value.
2. Convert the combo of year and month to a SAS date value, too.
3. Use the INTCK function to find the difference in months.

For example:

data dates ;
  input dt $18. yy mm ;
  mm_diff = intck ("mon", input (cats (yy, mm), yymmn6.), input (dt, anydtdte12.)) ;
  put mm_diff= ;
  cards ;
12 june 2017 00:15  2016  12
11 june 2018 00:15  2017   3
;
run ;

The log will print:

mm_diff=6
mm_diff=15

As a side note, the statement "there isn't a ready-made SAS date informat that will correctly handle your full date field" made elsewhere in this thread is incorrect. As the program snippet above shows, the ANYDTDTEw. informat handles it with aplomb. It's just incumbent upon the programmer to supply a sufficient informat width W. Above, it is selected as W=12. If you're reluctant to guess and/or count, just use ANYDTDTE32.

Regards,
Paul Dorfman

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have three numeric variables and the first one contains valid SAS **datetime** values you should first convert both to valid SAS **date** values. You can then use the INTCK() function to count months.

```
 nmonths = intck('month',datepart(VAR1),mdy(VAR3,1,VAR2));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful